# php shell_exec silently fails if it contains curly brackets for string substitution

Tags: php, shell

This simple command works fine if pasted in the terminal but in php it doesn't work.

```
for f in a b c d e; do echo ${f/a/p}; done; 2>&1
```

---

**Terminal**

```
p
b
c
d
e
```

---

**Php**

```
$command = "for f in a b c d e; do echo \${f/a/p}; done;";
$command .= " 2>&1";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

outputs nothing.

```
$command = "for f in a b c d e; do echo \$\{f/a/p\}; done;";
$command .= " 2>&1";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

output:

```
${f/a/p}
${f/a/p}
${f/a/p}
${f/a/p}
${f/a/p}
```

What's the problem??

Thanks

Comment: your interactive shell is probably `bash` but shell_exec is probably calling a posix shell (eg. `/bin/sh`) which doesn't understand pattern-substitution parameter expansions

Comment: @jhnc thanks, do you have some suggestion on how to make it works?

Comment: do the pattern substitution directly in php; save the script into a file and call `shell_exec('/bin/bash /path/to/script')`;  call `exec('/bin/bash -c 'shell commands')`

Comment: @jhnc thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @jhnc mentioned, the problem is it uses shell instead of bash.
You can execute bash with command argument like this:

```php
$command = 'for f in a b c d e; do echo ${f/a/p}; done;';
$command .= " 2>&1";
echo shell_exec("/bin/bash -c '" . $command. "'");
```

Output:

```
p
b
c
d
e
```